# Why is this query not behaving like I expect it to?

Tags: mysql

The query in question is

```
SELECT MAX(Date) as max, MIN(Date) as min FROM 
table 
WHERE Id = 'id' 
ORDER BY Date DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

And what I want it to do is return the maximum and minimum date of the most recent 100 records. What it does is it displays the min and max from ALL the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must *first* select the records you are interested in and *then* select `max()`  and `min()` from those.

```
SELECT max(Date) AS max,
       min(Date) AS min
  FROM ( SELECT *
           FROM t
          WHERE Id = 'id'
       ORDER BY Date DESC
          LIMIT 100) x;
```

Answer (score 2):

***Don't forget to escape the column with backtick.***

```
SELECT max(`date`) AS maxDate,
       min(`date`) AS minDate
FROM  ( 
         SELECT `date`
         FROM   myTable
         WHERE Id = 'id'
         ORDER BY `date` DESC
         LIMIT 100
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(Date) as min, max(Date) as max from
(
     SELECT Date FROM your_table 
     WHERE Id = 'id' 
     ORDER BY Date DESC  
     LIMIT 100
) x
```